# Problems reading a Boolean value in a Padrino/Datamapper app

Tags: ruby, sinatra, boolean, datamapper, padrino

I am working on a Padrino project that uses Datamapper as the ORM.  I have a User class that looks something like this:

```
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial                                           
  property :username, String,
  property :password, String
  property :confirmed, Boolean
  ...<snip>...
end
```

Now, in my `users` controller, I have this snippet of code:

```
user = User.get(current_user)
var1 = user.username
var2 = user.confirmed
```

Now, `var1` is populated perfectly fine with the contents of the `username` property of the model.  However, the next line throws the following error:

```
NoMethodError at /users/blah
undefined method 'confirmed' for User:Class
```

Looks like ruby is trying to treat the `.confirmed` as a method and not a property?  It seems to be happening on `Boolean` properties, and not `String` or `Integer` properties.

Is there something I have missed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataMapper properties are simply Ruby methods that DM makes for you (they are made using Ruby's meta-programming features when the `property` method is called). You could try

```
 p user.methods.sort - Object.methods
```

to get a listing of properties on the `User` object you created.

DM will have chosen to make the method `user.confirmed?` for the `:confirmed` property - it follows a loose Ruby convention of naming boolean methods with a `?` on the end. I have checked this by exploring the DataMapper code here: https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/blob/master/lib/dm-core/property.rb

Comment: Neil, you are indeed correct - DataMapper had created a method `user.confirmed?` which returns the true or false result I was after.  Thanks for doing the extra research and posting the link.